# How to get the list of lists

Tags: python

So I have a list of lists like this:

```
 mult_list = [ [1,2,3],[9,10,11].....[..,..,..]]
```

what i want is something that can return me 3 lists

```
where list_1 = [1,9...1st ele of each list]
      list_2 = [2,10... 2nd ele ]
     ..nth_list = [nth element of each_list]
```

So, this is for example sake.. the mul_list can have any number of fixed columns in the list .. num columns is 3 in our example.

SO something where you can think of it as a matrix.. and I am looking to have all the elements in same column in first list.
What is the pythonic way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` will get you the answer as a list of tuples. If you want a list of lists, do

```
map(lambda *row: list(row), *mult_list)
```

EDIT: more compactly,

```
map(list,zip(*mult_list))
```

Comment: Do you mean `map(list, zip(*mult_list))`?

Comment: ah. yes, that's much better. i've been coding with lambda functions all day, they are stuck in my head.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
>>> zip(*mult_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `zip` does exactly that:

```
>>> zip([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
[(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use zip(list1, list2);

mult_list = [ [1,2,3],[9,10,11] ]

so for that, you will get the result of [(1,9),(2,10),(3,10)]